# Passing object in Dlist.

Tags: java

The line "`if (l.head.item != 9`" gave me the error it said something like object is not compatible with int. I am really confused on why is that? How to fix it?

/*DListNode1*/

```
/* DListNode1.java */

public class DListNode1 {


  public Object item;
//  public short[][] colorVal;
  public DListNode1 prev;
  public DListNode1 next;


  DListNode1() {
    item = 0;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
  }

  DListNode1(Object i) {
    item = i;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
  }
}
//////////////
  /* Double linked list */
public class DList1 {

  protected DListNode1 head;
  protected DListNode1 tail;
  protected long size;

  public DList1() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
  }



  public DList1(Object a) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    tail = head;
    head.item = a;
    size = 1;
  }  
  public DList1(Object a, Object b) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    head.item = a;
    tail = new DListNode1();
    tail.item = b;
    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;
    size = 2;
  }

  public void insertFront(Object i) {
    DListNode1 temp = new DListNode1(i);
    if (size == 0) {
      head = temp;
      tail = temp;
    }
    else {
      temp.next = head;
      head.prev = temp;
      head = temp;
    } size++;  
  }


  public void removeFront() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return;
    }
    else if (size == 1) {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size--;
    }
    else {
      head = head.next;
      head.prev = null;
      size--;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode1 current = head;
    while (current != null) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }
/////////////

 public static void main(String[] args) {


    DList1 l = new DList1();
    l.insertFront(9);
     if (l.head.item != 9) {
        System.out.println("head.item is wrong.");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that the type of `l.head.item` is `Object`, and you can't compare that with an `int` using `!=` or `==`.

Options:

- Cast `l.head.item` to `Integer` or `int`:

  ```
  // This could be done in one step if you wanted
  int headValue = (int) l.head.item;
  if (headValue != 9)
  ```

  Or

  ```
  // This could be done in one step if you wanted
  Integer headValue = (Integer) l.head.item;
  if (headValue != 9)
  ```

  Or you could do it inline:

  ```
  if ((int) l.head.item != 9)
  ```
- Use `equals` instead, which will automatically box the `int` to an `Integer`.

  ```
  if (!head.equals(9))
  ```
- Make your type generic instead, so you'd have a `DListNode1<Integer>`, and you could then be certain that all node values were `Integer` references (or null), and the `!=` check would automatically unbox the `Integer` to an `int` and work.

Personally I'd definitely make this generic, but my *guess* is that you're relatively new to Java, and might not want to start with generics just yet.

Note that there's a difference between using `equals` and performing the unboxing: if the value of `l.head.item` is a reference to a non-`Integer` object, the first approach will throw a `ClassCastException` and the second will just go into the body of the `if` statement (as a string is *not* equal to 9, for example). Which of those is preferable depends on what you're trying to achieve in your bigger program: if it's entirely reasonable for your list to contain non-integers, you should use the `equals` check; if it actually indicates a programming error, then an exception is preferable as it alerts you to the error more quickly and stops your program from proceeding with invalid assumptions.

In both cases if `l.head.item` is `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`. This could be "fixed" using:

```
if (!Integer.valueOf(9).equals(l.head.item))
```

... but again it depends on what you want your code to do if the value is null.

Comment: Casting may produce ClassCaseException.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: Indeed. Was going to add about that.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: That depends on what you mean by "correct". You're *assuming* that proceeding is better than an exception. In most cases, a program knows what type is in a collection, and if that "knowledge" turns out to be false, an exception is a better option than proceeding regardless. Also, your code *doesn't* enter the `if` block if the value is a non-integer - even though it *isn't* equal to the integer 9. Maybe that's what the OP wants, maybe not...

Comment: Thanks and Hat off for your time spending with us, with your work load.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `DListNode1.item` is an Object not an Integer.  Try casting to a `Integer` and compare to an `Integer (9)`

Answer (score 0):

Compare using **equals** method.**'=='** will compare the refrence.

```
if(l.head.item.equals(new Integer(9))==false)
```

Answer (score -1):

It will give you error because int is primitive:

```
Incompatible operand types Object and int
```

Change your code to:

```
if (!l.head.item.equals(new Integer(9))) {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: See my comment on Kugathasan Abimaran's answer.